# split a string to array of arrays properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I have a string that looks like:

```js
const msg = " [['robot_arm', 'bc1', 'p_09_04_00'], ['operator', 'lc1', 'p_09_15_00'], ['robot_arm', 'oc1', 'p_08_17_00']]"
```

And I want to split it into an array of arrays of strings, I have tried to split this string as follows:

```
const msg_obj = new Array(JSON.parse(msg).split("["));
console.log(msg_obj);
for (let act_id in msg_obj) { 
    console.log(msg_obj[act_id]);
}
```

The problem is that I get unwanted characters/strings inside:

1. Empty strings `""`.
2. commas `,`.
3. square bracket `]`.

Can you please tell me if there is a better way to split this string into an array of arrays of strings without the unwanted output? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your single quotes aren't valid JSON. You can easily get the result you want by replacing the quotes before parsing:

```js
const msg = " [['robot_arm', 'bc1', 'p_09_04_00'], ['operator', 'lc1', 'p_09_15_00'], ['robot_arm', 'oc1', 'p_08_17_00']]"

const msg_obj = JSON.parse(msg.trim().replace(new RegExp("'", "g"), "\""));

console.log(msg_obj);
for (let act_id of msg_obj) {
  console.log(act_id);
}
```

Comment: I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data`

Comment: Please check my updated solution. I added the `.trim()` method to trim off excess whitespace. Are you sure that `msg` matches your real data?

Comment: "*`msg` matches your real data?*", no, actually I have reduced the `msg` to make a MWE, thanks.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

Your const `msg` is not a valid json string. maybe you can parse this string by this codes :

```
const msg = " [['robot_arm', 'bc1', 'p_09_04_00'], ['operator', 'lc1', 'p_09_15_00'], ['robot_arm', 'oc1', 'p_08_17_00']]"

msgArr = msg.split("], [").map(item => {  
    return item.trim().split(",").map(val => {
        return val.trim().replace(/\[|\'/g,'');  
    });  
})
```

[example.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlZSG.png)